# Shortcut Ghost: Running a Shortcut as the File?

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation, shortcut

I'm attempting to generate a shortcut that will run an executable file called `WAVistaWin7.exe`. Whenever the shortcut generates, I'll double-click it, and it will say "WAVistaWin7.exe cannot find 'wa.exe'." `wa.exe` is inside of the folder that it belongs. I then attempt to put a Batch file called `run.bat` containing two lines:

```
@echo off
WAVistaWin7.exe
```

I redirect the shorcut to run this file, and the Batch file states that it cannot find `WAVistaWin7.exe`. It's becoming evident that the shortcut is running independently of the file. Note that whenever I run either `WAVistaWin7.exe` or `run.bat` inside of the folder *directly* it works. How can I get the shortcut to run as the file?

[image: the result.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to set your working directory.  In the shortcut properties, you can set the **"Start in"** folder.

Alternatively, in your batch file you can change to the appropriate folder:

```
@echo off
pushd C:\Program Files\WA
WAVistWin7.exe
```